# C - can I use sscanf when half of the format is indeterminate?

Tags: c

I just recently started learning C, so don't assume I know anything...

Say I have a string like this

```
"XXX YYY ZZZ An uncertain string"
```

That I want to parse into 4 variables like so:

```
[XXX] [YYY] [ZZZ] [An uncertain string]
```

The first three values are guaranteed to exist separated by spaces, but everything after from `An` will have an indeterminate number of spaces.

I can already do:

```
sscanf(string, "%s %s %s", one, two, three);
```

To capture the first 3 values, but is there a way to capture the last bit with sscanf, or do I need to do something tricky with `strtok`?

Comment: How do you know that, you reach to the end of input ?.

Comment: @Shravan40 Well, I'm doing this inside a self contained function that takes an argument `char * string` that is a single line. Why do I need to determine the end? I'm guessing it might be null terminated?

Comment: @Shravan40 the input is a string

Comment: @Shravan40 Ok, there are no new lines in the string, and it terminates with one, so iharob's works well.

Comment: @AllTheTime Rather than include prevalent information in a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39339997/c-can-i-use-sscanf-when-half-of-the-format-is-indeterminate/39340114?noredirect=1#comment66011263_39339997) better to include that in  the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you mean that you want to capture 3 strings separated with spaces and then the rest of it

```
if (sscanf(string, "%s%s%s%[^\n]", one, two, three, four) != 4) {
    fprintf(stderr, "The string `%s' doesn't match the format\n");
}
```

And better be careful with a buffer overflow

```
char one[100];
char two[100];
char three[100];
char four[100];

if (sscanf(string, "%99s%99s%99s%99[^\n]", one, two, three, four) != 4) {
    fprintf(stderr, "The string `%s' doesn't match the format\n");
}
```

Comment: OP didn't mentioned that, 4th string may contain new line.

Comment: Well remove the `'\n'` but then, how do you determine the end of the 4th string?

Comment: This is what, i am asking from OP in question comment section.

Comment: Thanks! In my case '\n' is adequate to determine termination. This answer is perfect.

Answer (score 4):

Use `"%n"`to record where scanning stopped.  Always limit input by specifying maximum input width.  Check `sscanf()` results.

```
char one[10];
char two[10];
char three[10];
int n;
char * s = "XXX YYY ZZZ A something heyyy O";

if (sscanf(s, "%9s%9s%9s %n", one, two, three, &n) != 3) Handle_Failure();
else printf("'%s' '%s' '%s' '%s'\n", one, two, three, &s[n]);
```

Comment: Is there some advantage of using this method over the other answer? This one seems a little trickier to me.

Comment: @AllTheTime   `%9s` or what ever limiting width is better than `%s` as the latter invites problem should the input exceed  the  available space.  `%[^\n]"` fails should the  string, after `three`,  begin with `'\n'`.  `%[^\n]"` fails if the string after `three` is the empty string. This method does not have those short-comings.  A comment mentions `'\n'` is good for your goal.  Adding that to your post is better.   This answer does not depend on that comment.